# ionic2 steps to set production ready application, did you know bundle.js file is over 3mil char?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, angular, publishing, ionic2

i was surprised to see that app.bundle.js in my ionic app is nearly **3 millions char file !,** thats a nice and big framework "nearly 5X size of ionic1" anyhow.

as i'm getting very close to finish my app that i wrote from ground up to make use of angular2 and ionic2 -upgrading from angular1 and ngmaterial-

i'm starting to plan for release and how to turn this into production ready.

what are the side effects of having such big file uncompressed ? it takes my iOS emulated 16sec to bootstrap app ! but i'm thinking its just the emulator problem right ?

did anyone figured out a planned steps to how turn ionic2 app ready for publishing to iOS and android ?

is there anyway i can exclude directives/services/ parts of angular2/ionic2 that my app never uses ?

---Info----
i'm on Ionic Version: 2.0.0-beta.3, angular-2 version: 2.0.0-beta-12

Comment: Are you using TypeScript to develop your app? Do you use some minifier (ulify)? And did you check the PROD version of Angular?

Comment: Yes I use typescript, how can I get the prod. Version of anular ? I didn't use any minifier, actually I don't understand how ionic client pack my app :(